# custom cursor change based on cursor position - Royalslider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using royalslider. I have a function which allows navigation depending on cursor position.

```
}).data('royalSlider');
           slider.ev.on('rsSlideClick', function(e, origEvent) {
           var width = jQuery('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider').width;

           if (origEvent.pageX < (width/2)) {
                slider.prev();
                $('.rsOverflow').css({
                      'cursor': 'url(images/prevg.png), default'
           });

                } else {
                slider.next();
                $('.rsOverflow').css({
                       'cursor': 'url(images/nextg.png), default'
               });

              };
            });
           });
```

How can I modify this so that cursors change on hover - not just after click. Thanks

Comment: Why not creating two divs overlying the slide, one for left and one for right click. By doing so, you can add custom class to each div and handle different cursor. Plus, you can bind the click event in two different JS event handlers

Answer (score 0):

That would work if you change the css at that point trough javascript (jQuery).
For my solution you would hav to implement jQuery in your html before you use your following script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Than the code below would change the cursor

```js
var slider = $('#full-width-slider').royalSlider({
    autoHeight: true,
    ///// more options /////
    navigateByClick: false,
    prefix: 'image-'
},
}).data('royalSlider');

slider.ev.on('rsSlideClick', function(e, origEvent) {
    var width = jQuery('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider').width;
    if (origEvent.pageX < (width/2)) {
        slider.prev();
        // change css to prevg.png
        $('.rsOverflow').css({
         "cursor" : "url('images/prevg.png'), auto !important;"
        });
      
    } else {
        slider.next();
        // change css to nextg.png
        $('.rsOverflow').css({
         "cursor" : "url('images/nextg.png'), auto !important;"
        });
      
    };
});
});
```

Comment: Still navigates ok but does not change cursor from default grab. Not sure why?

Comment: is there a site online where I could watch the complete sourcecode?
Maybe the css rules do not overwrite the styles correctly.

Comment: maybe you could provide a working jsfiddle or something like that. Than I could look into it.

Comment: thanks Aaron - changed your syntax slightly and updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I saw your Example. I can't see a simple way of using the existing functions. Now you could try this:

```js
var mContainer = $('body'), 
    left = $(window).width() / 2,
    x, 
    y;

$(window).mousemove(function(evt){
 x = (evt.pageX - mContainer.offset().left) + $(window).scrollLeft();

 if(x < left) {
   $('.rsOverflow').css({
      "cursor" : "url('images/prevg.png'), auto !important;"
    });
  } else {
   $('.rsOverflow').css({
      "cursor" : "url('images/nextg.png'), auto !important;"
    });
  }

});
```

I am calculating the offset position of the cursor on the X-Axis. Now you can check if the cursor is on the left part of the site or on the right part. An can change the cursor accordingly. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is just to use two overlaying divs and remove them on touch as Yuri suggested. As the 
hover event is not written into the code its difficult to detect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
if(typeof ontouchstart !== 'undefined'){
    $('.prev1, .next1').remove();
}
});
</script>
```